# Error in sending email in Anypoint Studio (MuleSoft)

Tags: java, xml, email, mule, anypoint-studio

Everytime I try to send an email in AnyPoint Studio I get an error. I've tried sending it from other computers and it always works. It just doesn't seem to work in mine and I have no idea why.

This is my .xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:smtp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/smtp" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/smtp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/smtp/current/mule-smtp.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <smtp:gmail-connector name="Gmail" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Gmail"/>
    <flow name="attemptsendemailFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/sendemail" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <set-payload value="Hello" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <smtp:outbound-endpoint host="smtp.gmail.com"  user="myemail@gmail.com" password="mypwd" connector-ref="Gmail" to="myemail@gmail.com" from="myemail@gmail.com" subject="This is a test." responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SMTP"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

When I open the browser and type *localhost:8081/sendemail*, no email is sent and the browser prints this message.

```
Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=smtp://myemail%40gmail.com:<password>@smtp.gmail.com, connector=GmailSmtpConnector
{
  name=Gmail
  lifecycle=start
  this=17e9bc9e
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[smtp]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}
,  name='endpoint.smtp.myemail.gmail.com', mep=ONE_WAY, properties={fromAddress=myemail@gmail.com, toAddresses=myemail@gmail.com, subject=This is a test.}, transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started, responseTimeout=10000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=false}.
```

Funny thing is, I tested the exact same xml in other computers and it works.

Comment: I believe GMail can be a bit of a pain when sending SMTP email. I am not familar with Anypoint - can you get access to the logs for this SMTP conversation? If you can get the `EHLO` and the detailed server conversation (or show that it does not get that far) that is what would be most helpful.

Comment: Try adding the mail.debug property to your smtp outbound endpoint, eg: `<smtp:outbound-endpoint host="smtp.gmail.com"  user="myemail@gmail.com" password="mypwd" connector-ref="Gmail" to="myemail@gmail.com" from="myemail@gmail.com" subject="This is a test." responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SMTP"><property key="mail.debug" value="true"/></smtp:outbound-endpoint>` this will print debug messages to your console that will be useful for debugging this sort of problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would first test if your computer has connectivity to the Gmail servers.

Try "telnet smtp.gmail.com 587" or the Mac equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the port "587" in your flow.You can try the following configuration:

```
<smtp:outbound-endpoint
            connector-ref="emailConnector"
            host="smtp.gmail.com"
            port="587"
            user="<account name>%40gmail.com"
            password="<password>"
            to="<email addresses>"
            from="<account name>@gmail.com"
            subject="Test email message"/>
```

Also check if you have access to call the smtp.gmail.com from your local network